# Is there a substring method for basic JSON Path expressions in SOAPUI?

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsonpath

You've been big help in the past, so I'm hoping you can help me with this. So currently I'm working on a project at work using soapui to get back a giant Json payload. I need to create some assertions, and some of these will need to look at multiple nodes that have only one thing in common. That one thing is the first part of one of the nodes.

So what I'm looking for is some kind of substring command for JSONPath. Here is an example of what I'm looking for.

```
"BurgerJoints":    [
           {
         "JointName": "Bob's Burgers",
         "Price": 5
         },
        {
         "JointName": "Bob's Broiler Stand",
         "Price": 5
         },
         {
          "JointName": "Burger King",
          "Price": 5
         },
         {
           "JointName": "Bob's Beef Haven",
           "Price": 5
         },
         {
           "JointName": "Super Weenie Hut",
           "Price": 5
         }
 ]
```

In my example let's say I'm looking for all joints that are Bob's something. So my initial thought was to do something like 
       BurgerJoints[?(@.Substring(JointName,0,3)=="Bob")]
, to give me the nodes. But it looks like it didn't work. Can anyone tell me where my syntax went wrong, or if there isn't a way to do it in that way, what the best to accomplish my goal is?

Thanks guys!!

EDIT:

So I tried using Groovyscript to do it and I think I've gotten close, but somewhere the lists aren't populating. Here is the code I'm using

```
//imports
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//grab the response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
//define a JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

//verify the slurper isn't empty
assert !(jsonSlurper.isEmpty())

def jsonlist =[]

def i = 0

while (jsonSlurper.BurgerJoints[i] != null)
{
if(jsonSlurper.BurgerJoints[i].JointName.toString().substring(0,3)=="Bob")
    {
        jsonlist.add(jsonSlurper.BurgerJoints[i])

    }

    i++
}


def jsonlist2 = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonlist.toListString())

assert jsonlist2.size()==3
```

Still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Is the response shown in the question complete or only part of it? Because, could not find `jsonSlurper.PriceListItems` in the response, but groovy script has that in `while` loop.

Comment: I appologize, I changed my actual used code to match the situation I'm in. I basically just didn't use the object names or actual data from the database. So PriceListItems should be burgerjoints. I changed my code so that it should be correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Groovy Script which asserts list of `JointName` contains value `Bob's` with value 3. Please find the inline comments.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
//Defining json string a fixed value. Of course, you can use dynamic value
//using messageExchange like you shown in your question.
def jsonString = '''
{
"BurgerJoints":    [
           {
         "JointName": "Bob's Burgers",
         "Price": 5
         },
        {
         "JointName": "Bob's Broiler Stand",
         "Price": 5
         },
         {
          "JointName": "Burger King",
          "Price": 5
         },
         {
           "JointName": "Bob's Beef Haven",
           "Price": 5
         },
         {
           "JointName": "Super Weenie Hut",
           "Price": 5
         }
 ]
}
'''
//Parse the string, create slurper object
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
//find all JointNames which contains Bob's, and apply size, and assert with 3
assert json.BurgerJoints.findAll { it.JointName.contains('Bob\'s')}.size() == 3
```

**UPDATE:**  Based on the comment, adding additional statements that help to achieve what the author of this question is looking for.

```
def jointList = json.BurgerJoints.findAll { it.JointName.contains('Bob\'s')}
log.info jointList
```

**UPDATE 2:** Based on another comment, validate if Price of 1st and 2nd are equal from `jointList`

```
assert jointList[0].Price == jointList[1].Price
```

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for, but there is a next step and I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. My next step is to have those 3 nodes in a list by themselves, This is because I will be comparing prices and doing some other assertions once I have the nodes I'm looking for. So using the findAll that you just used, instead of asserting on it, can I add it to its own list?

Comment: @DonnieShannon, please check the update in the answer. `jointList` hold the filtered data.

Comment: I've been messing with this for a while and I'm missing one last step and was wondering if you could help me. I was able to populate that list, but now I want to use it. So say for the example I used the list we created. and I wanted to make sure that the price of the first restaurant was the same as the price as the second. I've tried jointList.BurgerBoints[0].Price and I've tried just jointList.Price, but neither seem to be able to pull up the result. What am I missing?

Comment: Original question was answered, but it is not accepted as answer. You had an additional question earlier in the comment which was again answered, still it is not accepted as answer. Now here I see third question.

Comment: @DonnieShannon, it is upto you to accept it as answer or not. Updated the answer for your previous comment.

Comment: Yes all of your answers were completely acceptable. I apologize, I wasn't aware it was necessary for me to click that, or in fact that the button even existed. Your answers have been very helpful so now that I know that an accept answer button exists, I will definitely do that.

Comment: Glad to know that the questions are answered to the satisfaction and thank you for accepting it. When a user creates an account in this site it show [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) so that user can use this site effectively.